# Control de Barra de progreso ON/OFF

Tags: javascript, html, uikit-3

Hola estoy tratando de hacer una sección donde el contenido se muestra aleatoriamente. Para esto estoy utilizando lo siguiente.

1. El contenido que se refresca cada x segundos.
2. Una barra de progreso que muestra el tiempo antes de refrescar
3. Un toogle on/off para activar y desactivar el auto/refresco.

Me he encontrado con el siguiente inconveniente; que cuando desactivas el refresco la barra de progreso continua corriendo y el resultado super raro.

Mi pregunta sería ¿como puedo sincronizar el toogle con la barra de progreso para que este se detenga una vez desactivas y viceversa?

Soy muy torpe con javascript no es muy fuerte espero que me pueda ayudar.

```js
function reFresh()
  {
  window.open(location.reload(true))
  }
    var repeticion = window.setInterval("reFresh()",30000);


    UIkit.util.ready(function () {

        var bar = document.getElementById('js-progressbar');

        var animate = setInterval(function () {

            bar.value += 10;

            if (bar.value >= bar.max) {
                clearInterval(animate);
            }

        }, 3300);

    });
```

```css
<div class="uk-grid-collapse uk-child-width-expand@m uk-margin" uk-grid uk-scrollspy="cls: uk-animation-fade; target: > div > delay: 500; repeat: true">
 
            
    <div class="uk-flex uk-flex-middle uk-flex-center">

        <div class="uk-card-body uk-width-expand uk-text-center uk-light uk-padding-small">
         
        <!-- Aqui el contenido -->
            <?php if ($this->checkPosition('letra_cancion')) : ?>
              <p><?php echo $this->renderPosition('letra_cancion'); ?></p><?php endif; ?>
           <!-- Fin del contenido -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Boton para refrescar manual -->

<div class="uk-text-center uk-padding-small">
 <a id="actualizar" href="javascript:location.reload()"  onclick="UIkit.notification({message: 'Volai-vai OUTRA!...', pos: 'top-center'})"><span uk-icon="icon: refresh; ratio: 1.5" uk-tooltip="Refrescar cantiga"></span></a>
</div>

<!-- Control de auto/refrescar -->

<div class="uk-text-center" uk-tooltip="Desactivar Aleatoria">
 <form class="toogle-dn" action="" onclick="window.clearInterval(repeticion);"><input class="toogle-dni" type="checkbox" id="toogle" /><label class="toogle-dni" for="toogle"></label></form>
  
</div>



<div class="progresgh"><progress id="js-progressbar" class="uk-progress parapan" value="10" max="100"></progress></div>
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.17/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.17/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.17/css/uikit.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para detener un setInterval puedes usar el método `clearInterval()`. Funciona así:

```
var miInterval = setInterval(function () { // Imprime hola cada 1 segundo
    console.log('Hola!');
}, 1000);

function detener() {
    clearInterval(miInterval);
}
```

En tu caso tendrías que hacer `clearInterval(animate)` para que la barra se detenga.

Puedes encontrar más información sobre la funcióin `clearInterval()` en este enlace: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp